# Why can I exceed my machine's RAM with R variables?

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, ram

I am on a computer with 16 GB RAM (Windows 7, 64-bit).  `memory.limit` at around this (roughly 16000 MB) around this amount and it was unable to cope with large arrays which would have pushed it over this limit.  However, I was able to set the memory limit much larger than the RAM (currently it is 2096000 MB!).  I assumed that this was a bit fictional and that the machine wouldn't really cope, but when I ran the code again, it coped fine, not taking all that long (< 5 minutes).

The `memory.size` is currently 24704 MB, substantially larger than the RAM, although my global environment has only one object (a list with a large array) of significant size: 11806 MB.

So my question is two-fold:

1. Why is my memory size so much larger than the only large object in my Global Environment (other than which I only have imported packages)
2. Why is my memory size allowed to be so much larger than the computer's RAM?

My memory profile is here:

```
   NULL      symbol    pairlist     closure environment     promise    language     special     builtin 
      1       14354      456204        6301        1232        6744      176976          45         667 
   char     logical     integer      double     complex   character         ...         any        list 
  25587       12555       65228       17992          22       82825           0           0       51683 
expression    bytecode externalptr     weakref         raw          S4 
         1       39002        2536         729         730         886
```

Comment: Note that `Mb` stands for mega**bits** and not mega*bytes*, so 24704 Mb is not 24.704 GB, it's 24704 / (1000 * 8) = 3.088 GB.

Comment: Thank you - I did mean megabytes and have now corrected (also apologies for being inconsistent in notation).  `help(memory.size)` in R says that the value is in Mb, but then it says that this is 1048576 (= 2^20) bytes, which would suggest that it really means MB.

Comment: I recommend reading through `?memory.limit` and `?memory.size`, mainly the limit is not bound to physical RAM, what will happen anyway is that R has to get in RAM the objects you're working on, if your array is wider than available ram, there'll be swapping of memory pages and performances will decrease. That's quite a vast subject on memory management and I'm unsure SO is the right place for this.

Comment: side note: memroy.profile gives you the number of object of each type, not their memory consumption, you have to use those numbers along with the  SEXP type size to get the memory usage by each type. All this mean digging in the code to get a view on how Lists, arrays,etc are stored in C++.

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai: I should think that you could post all that as an answer.  Very informative.

Comment: fair point, I'll try to write an answer with more detailed informations a little later ;)